# BiometricPrompt: Why should we check KeyguardManager.isDeviceSecure() before enabling setDeviceCredentialAllowed?

Tags: android, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

The documentation of `BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo`'s `setDeviceCredentialAllowed` method states:

> [...] Developers should first check KeyguardManager.isDeviceSecure() before enabling this. If the device is not secure, BiometricPrompt.ERROR_NO_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL will be returned in BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback.onAuthenticationError(int, CharSequence).

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder.html#setDeviceCredentialAllowed(boolean)

However, **in order to enable biometric authentication in the first place, you have to set up a device PIN or password**. Isn't this check (which is only available on API 23+) therefore superfluous when we already have `BiometricManager.canAuthenticate`?

Answer (score 4):

This is a great question! It might be important to provide a step-wise response. First, let's separate what's happening on a particular device vs what's happening in your app. Then we'll address the more specific question.

**Device**

A device running API 23+ may or may not have device login credentials setup. The owner of a device is not required to setup device PIN, pattern, password, or biometric templates. It's a choice.

**App**

A user should be able to install your app whether or not device login credentials have been setup. Therefore your app must be written in a way that handles use cases where login credentials haven't been setup.

**Answer to your more specific question**

[The recommendation](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd) is that you pass in a `CryptoObject` to `authenticate()` when implementing the biometrics API. If you follow that recommendation, then yes, you will check `canAuthenticate()` before calling `authenticate(promptInfo, cryptoObject)`. There are a number of reasons for this, which you can get from reading the blog post pointed to above.

Since your question is specifically about `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)`, it's important to recall what `canAuthenticate()` does. It checks for three things: whether there is biometric hardware available on the device, whether the user has enrolled templates, or whether the user has enabled biometric authentication.

Hence, you cannot use `canAuthenticate()` in your case since it's exclusively about biometrics whereas `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)` accepts device PIN, pattern or password.

Note that while the recommendation is that you use `CryptoObject`, `setDeviceCredentialAllowed()` is not compatible with `CryptoObject` nor with `setNegativeButtonText()`.

P.S. You may also benefit from reading [this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html).

Comment: Thank you!

So is this check for the case that someone has no biometrics enrolled but a device password set up?

And what is the appropriate way to to the same check below API 23? Because with `.setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)`, the BiometricPrompt can still fall back to the device's password there. So it would be nice to check if a password is set up there as well.

Comment: You write "Hence, you cannot use canAuthenticate() in your case since it's exclusively about biometrics"
But biometrics can't be enabled without setting a pin/password/pattern, right? So I still can't see the point of this check. If the device has biometrics, it has device credentials too.

Comment: Let B represent biometrics.
Let P represent PIN/pattern/password. 

**Then**

Your statement that B implies P is correct. In other words, if biometrics is enabled then it's safe to assume PIN/password/pattern is also enabled.

**BUT**

The converse is not true. Just because PIN/pattern/password is enabled does not necessarily mean biometric is enabled; after all, PIN/password were in circulation way before biometrics.

The doc is saying you need to make sure PIN/pattern/password are set on the device before trying to use them to login. Nothing to do with biometrics per se.

Comment: you have to imagine a situation where a device does **not** have biometrics, but has PIN/pattern/password set.

Comment: That makes sense. Now the only problem is that `KeyguardManager.isDeviceSecure` is only available on API level 23+. What about the devices on 21+ that also support PIN/pattern/password?

Comment: The functionalities of the biometrics library only work as far back as API 23. The Gradle dependency will compile on devices running API 14+, but the functions/methods are supported only on 23+.

Comment: Depending on the minSdkVersion level that your app is targeting, you may have to forego the convenient precheck and handle the error codes in `onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence)` yourself.

Comment: So there is no appropriate check for pin/pattern/password on AP 21-23? What about `KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure`?

Comment: Technically you can use `keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure` all the way back to API 16 as long as SIM-locked is not an issue for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to figure out if that would be an issue. Theoretically, the sim could be locked but my app could be running, right?  As I understand that, this could cause a false positive when I check for pin/pattern/password (even tho this would be unlikely)