# What is the correct flow to check for biometrics and pin/password with BiometricPrompt?

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

`BiometricManager` has a `canAuthenticate` method that can return either of 4 flags:

```
when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate()) {
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS ->
        Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "The user hasn't associated " +
        "any biometric credentials with their account.")
}
```

Now it seems logical to only trigger the `BiometricPrompt` if the result of that call is `BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS` and otherwise fall back to a different authentication method (i.e. app-specific password).

But if I set `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)` on the BiometricPrompt, it can **still use the device password** even if the `canAuthenticate` check does not return `BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS` (I think in this case it returns `BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED`).

I could additionally use `KeyguardManager` to check if a pin/password/pattern is set:

```
val kgm = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
if (kgm.isDeviceSecure) {
    [...]
}
```

But this only works on API 23+. However, `setDeviceCredentialAllowed` works on API levels below 23. But there seems to be no real alternative to check if a device password is set on these older devices

So my question is: With all these different options, what is the correct flow to show the user the appropriate authentication method? How should `canAuthenticate` and `isDeviceSecure` be used together and what check should be used for **API levels below 23**?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `canAuthenticate()` only when you are trying to authenticate exclusively with biometrics, not with anything else. And in that case the is a [well documented recommended approach](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd).

If your interest is `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)`, while the functionality itself only works on API 21+, you have a few implementation options depending on your minSdkVersion.

**API 23+**

```
 if (keyguardManager.isDeviceSecure()){
     biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
 }
```

**API 16 to pre-API 23**

```
if (keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure) {
   biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
}
```

`KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()` is equivalent to `isDeviceSecure()` unless the device is SIM-locked.

**API 14 to pre-API 16**

If you are targeting lower than API 16 or SIM-lock is an issue, then the callback `onAuthenticationError()` is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have some doubts:
1) `You should use canAuthenticate() only when you are trying to authenticate exclusively with biometrics, not with anything else`
Why is that? I mean, I can use both biometrics and device credentials as a fallback.

2) Could the sim lock with `isKeyguardSecure` cause false-positive checks if the sim is locked but no pin/pattern/password is set?

3) Why check for API levels below 21? To my knowledge, `setDeviceCredentialAllowed` doesn't work lower than `API 21`

Comment: 1) I answer a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59566044/biometricprompt-why-should-we-check-keyguardmanager-isdevicesecure-before-ena/59570158#59570158. 3) it all depends on how you want to implement your code if your app's minSdkVersion falls below 21.

Comment: That other question is also mine. I assume what you mean is that we should use `CryptoObject` and that's not compatible with `setDeviceCredentialAllowed`. But what if we use `BiometricPrompt` without `CryptoObject`?